# How to make asyncio cancel() to actually cancel the task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, python-mock

This code is stuck in an infinite loop, the `self.task.cancel()` seems to have no effect:

```
import asyncio

from unittest.mock import AsyncMock, patch


async def loop():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


class AsyncSleepMock(AsyncMock):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AsyncMock, self).__init__()
        self.task = None

    async def __call__(self, delay, *args, **kwargs):
        self.task.cancel()
        return await super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(delay, *args, **kwargs)


def create_async_sleep_mock():
    return AsyncSleepMock()


@patch("asyncio.sleep", new_callable=create_async_sleep_mock)
def main(async_sleep_mock):
    loop_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(loop())
    async_sleep_mock.task = loop_task
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(loop_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The goal is to make a mock of `asyncio.sleep()` that can break out from that infinite `loop()` that the application under test has. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.task.cancel()` marks the task as cancelled, but at that moment is this the active task on CPU. A task switch must occur to allow the scheduler to process the cancellation.

From the [cancel()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) docs:

> Request the Task to be cancelled.
>
> This arranges for a CancelledError exception to be thrown into the
> wrapped coroutine on the next cycle of the event loop.

I have inserted an unmocked `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to ensure the needed task switch, now it doesn't loop any more:

```
realsleep = asyncio.sleep

class AsyncSleepMock(AsyncMock):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AsyncMock, self).__init__()
        self.task = None

    async def __call__(self, delay, *args, **kwargs):
        self.task.cancel()
        await realsleep(0)
        return await super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(delay, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

For completness, I'm adding a quote from the [asyncio.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) description:

> sleep() always suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run.
>
> Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks
> to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking
> the event loop for the full duration of the function call.

Comment: Ok, looks like `sleep(0)` is an acceptable syntax to actually say 'yield to scheduler': https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284